# ReactNative Image | setNativeprops unable to change source

Tags: react-native

I have implemented the image onError method for network image and in error am trying to update the view with default image but the source property have no effect

```
onLoadError=(event)=>{
     alert('Img load error');
     this.imgPayIcn.setNativeProps({
       source :{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'} //not able to update view with new image... no effect


     });
```

Render method

```
<Image ref={(ref) => this.imgPayIcn = ref} source={this.props.source} style={{height:50,width:50}} resizeMode='cover' onError={this.onLoadError}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image in a component which handles the error:

```
class ImageWithFallback extends Component {
  state = {
    failed: false,
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.failed) {
      return <Image source={require('imageFallback.png')} />
    }
    return <Image {...this.props} onError={() => this.setState({ failed: true })} />
  }
}
```