# How to change the source of image by using setNativeProps in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing UI in react native, In this `<Image>` is used with source and i wanted to change the image source by setNativeProps not by state.

my code is:

```
<Image source={require('imagePath')} ref="icon"/>
```

On certain Event i want to change its source:

```
this.refs['icon'].setNativeProps({
    source: require('newImagePath')
  });
```

But nothing happens, its not change.
By using NativeProps the style of image is changed but the props like source and like that not changes.

So please give me a solution that how can i change the source of image on any certain event by using its refs or key (not by using this.setState)

Comment: Same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754845/reactnative-image-setnativeprops-unable-to-change-source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found the way you can change the image source by static image. We first need to use resolveAssetSource function to the static image and then put it in src.

```
import resolveAssetSource from 'resolveAssetSource';

...


var imgsrc = require('imagePath');

this.refs['icon'].setNativeProps({
   src: [resolveAssetSource(imgsrc)]
});
```

**Update:**

On IOS, use source instead of src.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for this help,But i wanna to change the static image using this.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please see it above, already tested and working

Comment: Here, the src is working fine in android platform but it doesnt working on iOS. So instead of using src , source is used which worked on iOS properly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback sachin. I'll update the answer. Btw, I tried on android using 'source' and not working

Comment: getting error `Cannot read property 'setNativeProps' of undefined` v 0.56

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DennisFrea who gave the answer I was looking for - simply adding the source as an array instead of an object.

Correct syntax

```
this._imageContainer.setNativeProps({
  source: [{ uri: newImageSource }]
})
```

Incorrect syntax

```
this._imageContainer.setNativeProps({
  source: { uri: newImageSource }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Crossplatform version:

```
const nativeProp = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'source' : 'src';
imageRef.current?.setNativeProps({
  [nativeProp]: [image], // array
});
```

Also, consider using Image prop `fadeDuration={0}` to disable fading on Android.

Answer (score -1):

I am towards thinking this is not possible because of the way RN handles the states and the way require() bundles the files.

However, I can think of two things to try:

1. ForceUpdate: Try calling this.refs['icon'].forceUpdate() after the native props to force a re render.
2. Set a wrapper in your image and update that wrapper, so you don't modify the original image source.

Something like this: [Programmatically add a component in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471921/programmatically-add-a-component-in-react-native/35471984#35471984)