# React Native : How to call child refs from the parent's event funtion?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

Have parent tag as `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` and child as `<Image>`, trying to change the image source from the parent `onPress` function, but getting error. how can I archive this using refs? or any other way to resolve it?

React-native version : 0.56

Error :

`Cannot read property 'favIcon' of undefined`

Sample Code :

```
const fav = require('../../images/favorite.png');
const nonfav = require('../../images/not_favorite.png');

updateFavorite = (id) => {
    this.props.refs.favIcon.source(fav);      
}

render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>                
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ this.updateFavorite.bind(this, 1) }>
         <View style={ styles.imageView }>
           <Image refs="favIcon" source={ nonfav } />                   
         </View>
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ this.updateFavorite.bind(this, 2) }>
         <View style={ styles.imageView }>
           <Image refs="favIcon" source={ nonfav } />                   
         </View>
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   </View>
  )
}
```

**Note** : change only the child image of onPressed, not all images.

Comment: Few questions - What is refs? I have seen only ref. If refs is a thing then why are you using it like this " this.props.refs etc". Have you tried ref as a function?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal, changed refs to ref in all place `this.props.ref.favIcon.source(fav); ` getting same error like above.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal - how to use ref as function?

Answer (score 0):

try it using nativeProps, like

```
import resolveAssetSource from 'resolveAssetSource';

this.refs['favIcon'].setNativeProps({
   src: [resolveAssetSource(fav)]
});
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234873/how-to-change-the-source-of-image-by-using-setnativeprops-in-react-native) for more.

It might not work with react-native 0.50+ versions but according to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18874#issuecomment-424153585) comment it should work with `0.57.1`

Comment: getting error `Cannot read property 'setNativeProps' of undefined`.

Comment: checking it with android or ios?

Comment: checking in android

Comment: I am using 0.56, need any alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Updating properties of elements in React is best done by calling `setState` method. Try the following

```
updateFavorite = (event) => {
  event.target.setAttribute('src', fav)
}

render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>       
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
         <View style={ styles.imageView }>
           <img ref={ref => this.favIcon = ref} src={nonFav} onPress={ this.updateFavorite }/>                   
         </View>
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>         
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
         <View style={ styles.imageView }>
           <img ref={ref => this.favIcon = ref} src={nonFav} onPress={ this.updateFavorite } />                   
         </View>
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: getting error - `Cannot read property 'favIcon' of undefined`

Comment: I think, it may cause any issue from the function?, Am I calling right?

Comment: @151291 Updated my answer

Comment: If we have multiple Images will apply for all right?, I need to apply only for the one, means child of `<TouchableWithoutFeedback`>, I have many.

Comment: @151291 You can leave the other `<Image />` as is using the hardcoded `source` attribute. Just change the `source` attribute of the one you want to update to take from `this.state.source`.

Comment: I did not get the above!

Comment: if we do  `this.setState({source: this.fav});` it will apply for all image right?

Comment: @151291 I think I understand what you want now. You only want to change the image to fav of a certain >img /> only. Try moving onPress to `img` element (and use `img` instead of `Image`). Updated my answer

Comment: is `<img>` will support in react-native v0.56?, it gives error!